# Prove that $f(x):=\begin{cases}e^{-\frac{1}x},\,\text{if}\, x>0\\0,\,\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ is of class $C^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

So I ask to prove that the function $f(x):=\begin{cases}e^{-\frac{1}x},\,\text{if}\, x>0\\0\,\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ is of class $C^\infty$.

Clearly $f\in C^0$ since $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=0$ and since in $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,+\infty)$ the function $f$ agrees with functions of class $C^\infty$ so to prove the statement we have to prove that $f^n(0)=0$ but unfortunately I can't prove this. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: There is a useful proof of this at [Wikipedia: Non-analytic smooth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#The_function_is_smooth).

Comment: Yeah, that's classical ...

Comment: @Jam I read your link: however I'd like to have a better expression for the polynomial $p_n$, do you know one?

Comment: Then, formally I shall verify by induction that $$f^{(n)}(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{p_n(x)}{x^{2n}}f(x),\,\text{if}\,x>0\\0,\,\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ where $p_1(x):=1$ and $p_{n+1}(x):=x^2p'_n(x)-(2nx-1)p_n(x)$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Did you click the [show] button to the right of "Detailed proof of smoothness"? It tells you how to do the induction. A closed form for $p_n$ isn't needed; the recurrence relation it enough.

Comment: @Jam Excuse me but I have not saw the button. Anyway now I have read: all clear, thanks too much for your reference!!!

Comment: @OliverDiaz The answer are similar but I ask to prove that $f\in C^\infty$  whereas it seems to me that the question you showed ask different things about the function $f$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I accepted your feadback for mistake.

Comment: @Antonio Maria Di Mauro: The polynomials that appears in $f^{(n)}$ are related to the Hermite polynomials.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Don't worry: I'm not offended by your criticism. Anyway reading the Wikpedia's article I understood what was not clear to me. Anyway I think that tomorrow (here is late now) I will answer to the question (do you want to do it?) rewriting with additional words what is written in Wikipedia's areticle: so if you like (I'd like it) then you can read my answer and say to me if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The $n$th derivative of $e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ will always be a sum of powers of $x$ times $e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$. We can show each of these terms approaches 0 as $x\to 0$ by substituting $x=\frac{1}{t}$ and using L'Hospital's rule as $t \to \infty$.